# Recoding over multiple data frames in R

Tags: r

(edited to reflect help...I'm not doing great with formatting, but appreciate the feedback)

I'm a bit stuck on what I suspect is an easy enough problem. I have multiple different data sets that I have loaded into R, all of which have different numbers of observations, but all of which have two variables named "A1," "A2," and "A3".  I want to create a new variable in each of the three data frames that contains the value held in "A1" if A3 contains a value greater than zero, and the value held in "A2" if A3 contains a value less than zero. Seems simple enough, right?

My attempt at this code uses this faux-data:

```
set.seed(1)
A1=seq(1,100,length=100)
A2=seq(-100,-1,length=100)
A3=runif(100,-1,1)
df1=cbind(A1,A2,A3)

A3=runif(100,-1,1)
df2=cbind(A1,A2,A3)
```

I'm about a thousand percent sure that R has some functionality for creating the same named variable in multiple data frames, but I have tried doing this with lapply:

```
mylist=list(df1,df2)
lapply(mylist,function(x){
  x$newVar=x$A1
  x$newVar[x$A3>0]=x$A2[x$A3>0]
  return(x)
})
```

But the newVar is not available for me once I leave the lapply loop. For example, if I ask for the mean of the new variable:
    mean(df1$newVar)
    [1] NA
    Warning message:
    In mean.default(df1$newVar) :
    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well first of all, `df1` and `df2` are not `data.frames` but matrices (the dollar syntax doesn't work on matrices).
In fact, if you do:

```
set.seed(1)
A1=seq(1,100,length=100)
A2=seq(-100,-1,length=100)
A3=runif(100,-1,1)
df1=as.data.frame(cbind(A1,A2,A3))

A3=runif(100,-1,1)
df2=as.data.frame(cbind(A1,A2,A3))

mylist=list(df1,df2)
lapply(mylist,function(x){
  x$newVar=x$A1
  x$newVar[x$A3>0]=x$A2
})
```

the code *almost* works but gives some warnings. In fact, there's still an error in the last line of the function called by `lapply`. If you change it like this, it works as expected:

```
lapply(mylist,function(x){
  x$newVar=x$A1
  x$newVar[x$A3>0]=x$A2[x$A3>0] # you need to subset x$A2 otherwise it's too long
  return(x) # better to state explicitly what's the return value
})
```

---

**EDIT** (as per comment):

as basically always happens in R, functions do not mutate existing objects but return brand new objects.
So, in this case `df1` and `df2` are still the same but `lapply` returns a list with the expected 2 new data.frames i.e. :

```
resultList <- lapply(mylist,function(x){
  x$newVar=x$A1
  x$newVar[x$A3>0]=x$A2[x$A3>0]
  return(x)
})

newDf1 <- resultList[[1]]
newDf2 <- resultList[[2]]
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me so quickly, and helping me get away from the errors.  Now I have:`
   lapply(mylist,function(x){
       x$newVar=x$A1
       x$newVar[x$A3>0]=x$A2[x$A3>0]
       return(x)
    })
`
But when I later look at df1 and df2, they still only have 3 variables: A1, A2, and A3. No "newVar".

    names(df1)
    [1] "A1" "A2" "A3"

What am I doing incorrectly?