# How to solve "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments" issue in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

Im doing random forest predictions using R.
My Aggregate_sample.csv data set.

```
Company Index,Is Customer,videos,videos
watched,tutorials,workshops,casestudies,productpages,other,totalActivities,youngTitleCount,
oldTitleCount,Median between two Activities,Max between 2 activities,
Time since100thactivity
STPT,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,19,22,0,22,120,64074480,0
STPR,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,61,64,0,64,120,56004420,0
PLNRTKNLJS,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,25,25,25,0,810,4349940,0
ASSSNNSP,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,17,20,0,20,60,2220,0
STPP,1,164,32,25,36,26,0,2525,2808,498,2310,60,2938260,76789992
AJKMPTNKSL,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0
FNKL,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,21,22,0,22,300,2415900,0
FNKK,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,0,60,60,0
FNKN,1,2,0,1,0,0,0,22,25,0,25,480,150840,0
```

Following is my R script

```
 # Install and load required packages for decision trees and forests
library(rpart)
install.packages('randomForest')
library(randomForest)

Aggregate <- read.csv("~/Documents/Machine Lerning/preprocessed data/Aggregate_sample.csv")

# splitdf function
splitdf <- function(dataframe, seed=NULL) {
if (!is.null(seed)) set.seed(seed)
index <- 1:nrow(dataframe)
trainindex <- sample(index, trunc(length(index)*0.7))
trainset <- dataframe[trainindex, ]
testset <- dataframe[-trainindex, ]
list(trainset=trainset,testset=testset)
}

splits <- splitdf(Aggregate, seed=808)

#it returns a list - two data frames called trainset and testset
str(splits)

lapply(splits,nrow)

#view the first few columns in each data frame
lapply(splits,head)

training <- splits$trainset
testing  <- splits$testset

#fit the randomforest model
model <- randomForest(as.factor(Aggregate$Is.Customer) ~ Aggregate$seniorTitleCount +
Aggregate$juniorTitleCount + Aggregate$totalActivities + Aggregate$Max.between.2.activities
+ Aggregate$Time.since.100th.activity + Aggregate$downloads , data=training,
importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)

#print(mode)
# what are the important variables
varImpPlot(model)
```

But i'm keep getting following error and can not proceed.It seems there's something wrong with my IsCustomer column but it's just a column with "0" and "1"s(I don't have any NAs in my dataset).

`Error in [<-.factor("*tmp*", keep, value = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1",  : 
  NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments
  In addition: Warning message:
'newdata' had 3 rows but variables found have 9 rows`

I read following question which seems to be related to my question but couldn't find an answer from it.
[Assigning within a lapply "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339254/assigning-within-a-lapply-nas-are-not-allowed-in-subscripted-assignments)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That fact that you have `Aggregate$` in the formula and also are specifying a `data=` parameter seems suspicious. But if you really want help, you'll need to provide a minimal [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) which includes sample input data so we tell you exactly why that's happening.

Comment: may be there are NAs in the data. Try `na.roughfix` function in random forest package itself

Comment: Thanks for replying. @MrFlick i updated with more information. koundy, There's no NAs in my csv as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to draw your data only form the `training` data.frame, so you should not be referencing `Aggregate` in your formula. Using the variable names actually in your test data, this seems to work just fine.

```
randomForest(as.factor(Is.Customer) ~ oldTitleCount +
   youngTitleCount + totalActivities + Max.between.2.activities +
    Time.since100thactivity + videos , 
data=training,
importance=TRUE, ntree=2000)
```

which returns

```
Call:
 randomForest(formula = as.factor(Is.Customer) ~ oldTitleCount +      youngTitleCount + totalActivities + Max.between.2.activities +      Time.since100thactivity + videos, data = training, importance = TRUE,      ntree = 2000) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 2000
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 16.67%
Confusion matrix:
  0 1 class.error
0 4 0         0.0
1 1 1         0.5
```

Comment: Thanks allot. It works..!! I just started R day before yesterday. I feel pretty dumb now :) . Thanks again.