# R -- Create Variable in List of Data Frames Based on a Sequence

Tags: r, list

I have created a series of data frames that are ordered in sequence (e.g., `df1`, `df2`, `df3`, `df4`, ...).  I have pulled these data frames together into a list (`ldf`) and would now like to create a variable (`z`) that features the number associated with each data frame, such that the variable `z` for element `df1` in `ldf` will equal `1`, whereas `z = 2` for `df2` in `ldf`.

In reality I have several thousand data frames, but as an example, I put together the following code to build the data frames and wrap them into a list:

```
for (i in 1:4) {
  assign(paste0('df', i), data.frame(x = rep(1:100),
                                     y = seq(from = 1,
                                             to = 1000,
                                             length = 100)))
}

ldf <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)
```

Borrowing a bit of code from another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323236/recoding-over-multiple-data-frames-in-r), I attempted to create the variable `z` with:

```
ldf <- lapply(ldf, function(x) {
  x$z = seq(1:4)
  return(x)
})
```

Not surprisingly, this just loops 1-4 repeatedly over the 100 observations in each data frame, rather than assigning `1` for `df1`, `2` for `df2`, `3` for `df3`, and `4` for `df4` (as I desire).

If anyone who is more familiar with lists could help me figure this out I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to iterate over two lists/vectors simultaneously, you can either use `mapply()` or `Map`. Here's code using the latter

```
Map(function(x,z) cbind(x,z=z), ldf, 1:4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this address the request?

```
ldf$z <- seq_along(ldf)
```